# Flatten a PDF with PHP (PDFTK)

Tags: php, pdf, pdftk, flatten

I am using PDFTK to flatten a PDF with PHP. Problem is that all special characters (É,è,à, etc.) disappear once flattened. Tried UTF-8, unicode chars, htmlentities, etc., it's all the same as a result.

Therefore, I would like to solve PDFTK issue OR use another script to achieve this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the font set for all fields was causing the problem.
If you run into that kind of problem and you're sure about your encoding, try another font, the one you use may be corrupted like in my case.